# Why are my div's not placed "inside" the wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, the `#wrapper` div contains the `#left` and the `#right` div. But they do not turn out to be contained inside the `#wrapper` div.

I want them to be treated as the content of the `#wrapper` div, so they are contained inside it, leaving the `10px` `padding` applied to the `#wrapper`. Why are they displaced?

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cros1mrv/)**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Alpha</div>
    <div id="right">Bravo</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows.

```
#wrapper {
    background-color:grey;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-botton: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
#left {
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    background-color:pink;
    float:right;
}
```

I want to solve this without manipulating position attributes of the `#wrapper` as that might disrupt the normal structure of my page (I'm afraid so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are floating them so they sit outside of the DOM flow. If you want the parent to consider them, add `overflow: hidden` to the parent CSS or add a div at the bottom of the container with the rule `clear: both;`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cros1mrv/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should set the overflow of your wrapper to `overflow: auto` to flow around your floating divs.

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-botton: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cros1mrv/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Because of floating. One way to clear that is to use:

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```